# Calculating area of x² at [1,3] with Riemann-sums

Tags: calculus

How can I calculate the area under $f(x) = x^2$ exactly, using Riemann-sums with $n$ cuboids, and then letting $n$ near infinity, at the interval $[1,3]$?

Comment: Quite a lot of ways. I know that the answer is 26/3(by integration and by substracting the area of [0,3] and the area of [0,1]), but how to do it with Riemann-sums, I just can't find the way to do it.

Comment: See whether this helps you: https://www3.nd.edu/~apilking/Math10550/Lectures/24.%20Areas%20and%20Distances.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link Rohan, although it just states what I have already received during my math classes. I can do the area under [0,1], [0,2] and [1,2], but when I tried to combine the ways to do [0,2] and [1,2], it didn't work: I ended up at 6 2/3, which is 2 less than the actual answer. 
Someone doing a step-by-step solution would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

We'll first need to partition the interval into $n$ pieces.

They will each be an $n$th of the length of the interval.
So, this will be $\frac{3-1}{n} = \frac{2}{n}$.

So, let $L_n$ be the $n$th Riemann sum.  This will be:
$$L_n =\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{2}{n}f(x_i)$$
Here, we want the $x_i$ to be the left endpoint each time.
To get this, we can say that $x_i = 1+\frac{2}{n}\times k$.
As we're starting $k$ at $1$, and we want $x_1 = 1$, this should really be $x_i = 1+\frac{2}{n}(k-1)$.
So, we have that:
$$L_n = \frac{2}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n\left(1+\frac{2}{n}(k-1)\right)^2$$
The summands here simplify to $1+\frac{4}{n}(k-1)+\frac{4}{n^2}(k-1)^2$.
As our sum is with respect to $k$, we'll want to group similar powers of $k$ together.
This gets us:
$$1+\frac{4}{n}k-\frac{4}{n}+\frac{4}{n^2}k^2-\frac{8}{n^2}k+\frac{4}{n^2} = \frac{4}{n^2}k^2+\left(\frac{4}{n}-\frac{8}{n^2}\right)k+\left(1-\frac{4}{n}+\frac{4}{n^2}\right)$$
Now, we're going to need the following results:
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n 1 = n,\quad \sum_{k = 1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2},\quad \sum_{k = 1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Now, we can substitute this into our prior calculation to get that:
\begin{align*}
L_n & = \frac{2}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{4}{n^2}k^2+\left(\frac{4}{n}-\frac{8}{n^2}\right)k+\left(1-\frac{4}{n}+\frac{4}{n^2}\right) \\
& = \frac{8}{n^3}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\left(\frac{8}{n^2}-\frac{16}{n^3}\right)\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+2\left(1-\frac{4}{n}+\frac{4}{n^2}\right)
\end{align*}
Now, we can look at $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ of this, to get that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}L_n = \frac{16}{6}+4+2 = \frac{8}{3}+6 = \frac{26}{3}$$

Comment: I knew that I was doing something wrong! The height is multiplied by k-1, not k! Thanks man!